# Is it good to generate Html page elements using AJAX queries?

Tags: javascript, ajax

depending upon UI inputs, i need to dynamically change (create or hide) other UI elements.
Also i don't want to refresh my page.Is it good to generate Html page elements using AJAX queries? Also what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Of course you need to create HTML Elements. How else do you want something to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)'s [html](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) binding to do the work. Here is the idea:

1. Create a global viewModel:

   `var _viewModel = {
     body: ko.observable()
   }`
2. In the html page:

   `<div id="dynamic-part" data-bind="html: body" ></div>`
3. In the javascript

   `ko.applyBindings(_viewModel, $('#dynamic-part')[0]);`
4. whenever you want to load the dynamic-part, you can have kind of javascript code like follows:
   `$.get('/some/new/page/part', function(data) {_viewModel.html(data);});`

When you apply the above technology along with [sammy](http://sammyjs.org) and [LAB](http://labjs.com), you will get a very powerful one-page web application, where all the pages of the application can be load with ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the way it's done is that the initial page has  tags with identifiers, but no content in the divs.  As your AJAX results come back, you set the innerHTML of those divs to the retrieved content, addressing them by identifier.  [Here's a page](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=169337) which explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to copy with the technical stuff.

How to make an AJAX request in the first place?
I would choose the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library. This has a [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function.

Then you decide:
Do you give back just some data and build the HTML content in JavaScript? (Here again jQuery is a good way to do it)
Or do you build the HTML on the server-side and just put it in my document using the ajax callback method `success`?

That's for starter